# Making a complete arc out of a rectangle upper part in sketch

Tags: sketch-app, corners

after some months I am playing with sketch app but can't find the option to apply max. border radius on a rectangles upper half creating a complete arch.

Any ideas? In Illustrator this is dead simple.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by manually typing in a radius value larger than 100 in the object properties.

Comment: To add to this answer: you first have to select the nodes that you want to set the radius value for, then type this in.